# Curvature operator on Kahler manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, curvature

Is positive curvature operator on a Kaehler manifold equivalent to the curvature operator being positive on real $(1, 1)$-forms? How do these conditions translate into the components of the curvature tensor? In terms of $R_{ijkl}$ and $R_{\alpha\bar{\beta}\gamma\bar{\delta}}$?

Comment: Either Kähler or Kaehler would be a correct spelling, but if it were Kahler it would be pronounced differently.